# How to copy files from remote server's share drive to my local computer using Ant

Tags: windows, ant

How to copy files from remote server's share drive to my local computer using an Ant script?

What I do currently is

1. Open Windows explorer
2. Type the location of the folder (like //192.168.2.12/xyz/abc)
3. Ask for credentials, I provide those
4. copy the file and paste it on the local server

I want to perform the same things through an Ant script.

Comment: ant is not specialized for Windows. It is better to use a command-line script. See "net.exe" for mounting remote shares.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ant Task To Copy To Windows Share (SMB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059619/ant-task-to-copy-to-windows-share-smb)